# Simba Spark JDBC driver - DatabaseMetaData.getColumns() does not work

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, azure-databricks

I am trying to get metadata for a column in a table in Spark on Databricks. I am using the Simba JDBC driver for Spark (SimbaSparkJDBC42-2.6.16.1020.jar)

```
DatabaseMetaData metadata = conn.getMetaData();
      ResultSet resultSet = metadata.getColumns("SPARK", "default", "testtable", "id");
      while (resultSet.next()) {
        String name = resultSet.getString("COLUMN_NAME");
        String type = resultSet.getString("TYPE_NAME");
        int size = resultSet.getInt("COLUMN_SIZE");

        System.out.println("Column name: [" + name + "]; type: [" + type + "]; size: [" + size + "]");
      }
```

I have 5 columns with the primary key being the column 'id' (bigint) and the rest of the column of datatype string. The code above gives an output when I replace the column name by 'null' (I can then see the all the columns details) and when I look for the column name pattern 'id' (primary key of my tables) but **is empty for all the other column** I test with... any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `metadata.getColumns("SPARK", "DEFAULT", "TESTTABLE", "ID")`? The patterns must match the identifiers as stored in the database, and a lot of databases will store unquoted identifiers as uppercase in their metadata tables.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Yes I tried upper and lower case but without luck. I think this problem is specific to the SimbaSpark JDBC driver... is this something you have used before?

Comment: No, I haven't used SimbaSpark itself, I'm just going by educated guess based on expected behaviour for a JDBC driver.